# new (функция конструктор)

Tags: javascript, конструктор

Когда вызываешь функцию с new, то берется конструктор этой функции и создается объект. Как можно вызвать такую функцию так, чтобы она вернула значение аргумента. Например, есть у меня такой код:

```js
function num(a) {
  this.a = Number(a);
};

var b = new num(2).a;

console.log(b) // 2
```

Как я могу вызвать такую функцию без указания ключа, то есть также, как работает new Number(2), чтобы вернуть аргумент без ключа?

Comment: что? что такое ключ в вашем понимании? зачем вам возвращать аргумент, который вы сами же передаете?

Comment: Хочу, чтобы var b = new a(2) возвращал 2 без имен, просто new a(2) = 2

Comment: Технически никак. `new` всегда возвращает объект. И совершенно непонятен смысл вашей хотелки

Comment: смысл хотелки — понять, как работает new и почему популярные new (string, date, Number, reg exp) возвращает одним своим вызовом данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function num(a) {
  this.a = Number(a);
}
num.prototype.valueOf = function() { return this.a; };

var b = new num(2);
console.log(b == 2) // true
console.log(b == 3) // false
```

Comment: спасибо, а как я теперь можно вывести это значение? чтобы получилось — console.log(b) // 2